# Vue Babel, set right chuckFileName syntax-dynamic-import

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

> **Note :** (i think) I'am becoming a novice in vue

Hi, i have project fullstack laravel & vue, if i want to build / watch, in directory /public i found irregularities like this:

```
> Part of folder structure:

...
...
config/
node_modules/
public/
  |-- index.js // this my vue index file
  |-- 0.js     // this my page of index file
  |-- 1.js     // and this too
  |-- favicon.ico
  |-- mix-manifest.json
resoures/
...
...
```

my vue route :

```
{
  root: 'account',
  base: 'account',
  mode: 'history',
  routes:[
    {
      name: 'Login',
      path: '/',
      component: () => import(
        './pages/login')
    },
    {
      name: 'Activation',
      path: '/activation',
      component: () => import('./pages/activation')
    }
  ]
}
```

> **Question** : can i config to change name and directory for 0.js and 1.js to pages/login.js and pages/activation.js ?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, you can config to change the name.  Here's the quirk, don't use dynamic import if you don't have to.  Laravel Mix does not current support it; as in, you will run into issues other issues like javascript in your css file.  Problem is with WebPack4 and we're waiting for WebPack5 to resolve.

Comment: @Noogen, i  have solve but i dont know my method is right or not, i just use `magic comment` in webpack and i use webpackChunkName each dynamic import and wow, it's work!. is this a problem?